# Selenium wait for an element

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to learn selenium, one of the issues I am having is waiting for elements, I'll explain it.

I am doing a java program to auto translate by using google translate.
But due to the asynchronous nature of google translate there are no way to get the element without waiting for it, code crashes because it doesn't find the element, and the element doesn't exist at the time the code requires it, you must wait a little until the server respond your request.

I think it is not a estrange situation dealing with selenium and webpages so I think there must be an easy way to do it.
By the moment this is the code I have created to manage the situation.

```
public void translation(String s) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Robots\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebElement webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

> this is the code I think there should be a better way to do,
>
> I have used a method to wait until the translation is ready

```
    waitForElement("//*[@id='result_box']");


    System.out.println("prhase: " + s + " tranlsation: " + response.getText());

    webDriver.close();
}

private void waitForElement(String element) {
    WebElement response;
    do {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(element));

    } while (response.getText().isEmpty());
}
```

Can you say me how to do it easy please?

Comment: There is a multiple wait methods to wait for an element refer this [link]http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp it will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Thread.sleep which isn't actually waiting for the element, it's just waiting for 3 seconds regardless.

You could do something like this instead.

```
private void waitForElement(String element) {
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 10); // Wait for 10 seconds.
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(element)));
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));

}
```

There is no need for the try / catch block either unless your expecting something weird to happen. The above code, will wait for the element to appear for 10 seconds. Not sure if you need to use the last line of code or not.

Hope it helps!

Comment: No prob, Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Thread.sleep()` and `while` you should try using [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to wait until with [`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as below :-

```
private WebElement waitForElement(String element) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10); //It will wait upto 10 seconds

    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(element))); 
}
```

Now you can modified your `translation` method as below :-

```
public void translation(String s) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Robots\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebElement webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebElement response = waitForElement("//*[@id='result_box']");

    System.out.println("prhase: " + s + " tranlsation: " + response.getText());

    webDriver.close();
}
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: It works, thanks. I have choosen the answer of "Moser" as the best because you have more points, just to make him grow :)

Comment: @DavidMarciel ok no problem...:)